Studying irreducibility in an integral domain by looking at the image of a homomorphism between multiplicative monoids
Fact number 1: A polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ whose leading coefficient is not divided by $p$ is irreducible if its image through a ring homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb Z_p$ is. And i know that this also works for other ring homomorphisms, like the shift $x \mapsto x + a$.
Fact number 2: An element of the quadratic extension of the integrers $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is irreducible if its norm is, in the integers.
Are those two facts manifestations of the same thing? and it’s not something about image of integral domains through ring homomorphisms, because the norm isn’t. Rather between the multiplicative group (monoid?) and a multiplicative group (monoid? because the image of the norm for example is not a group under addition).
If this is a thing, does it have a name?
Thank you so much for reading :)

Yes it's the same. The notion of an irreducible element indeed has nothing to do with the additive structure. It works in every commutative monoid (say, written multiplicatively). It is a non-unit such that for every factorization of it with two elements one of these is a unit. In the context of integral domains, we apply it to the commutative monoid of non-zero elements.
Now here is the small result that combines your two facts.

If $f : M \to N$ is a homomorphism of commutative monoids such that $f$ reflects units ($m$ is a unit if $f(m)$ is a unit), then $f$ also reflects irreducible elements.

The proof is easy. If $f(m)$ is irreducible, then $m$ is not a unit (otherwise $f(m)$ would be one), and if $m=ab$ then $f(m)=f(a)f(b)$, so one of these is a unit, meaning that one of $a,b$ is a unit. $\checkmark$
So in your examples one only has to prove that the homomorphisms reflect units. The first one, reducing a polynomial mod $p$, actually does not have this property in general (consider $2X+1$ for $p=2$), but for the example it suffices to show this for non-constant polynomials whose leading coefficient is coprime to $p$, where it is true. For the second example, notice that the norm can be defined as $N(x) = x \cdot a(x)$ for some automorphism $a$. So when $N(x)$ is a unit, it follows immediately that $x$ is a unit.

thanks for the answer! so i guess they are the same thing, even if the reduction modulo a prime is more delicate.

Yes it's the same. I made an edit to make this hopefully more clear.
